# What is the most efficient way of having an entire Google Group edit a single Google document?

Tags: google-drive, google-groups, google-drive-sharing

I have created a Google Group for my development team, and we've agreed to have Google as a host of our design document.

Every member needs to be able to edit the design document, and I'm not sure how to do that. Is it possible to create a Google document as a group, instead of as an individual? How can an individual share the document with the group easily, if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, share it with edit capability with the group's email address.

Done :)

Comment: Yeah, I managed to do it in the mean time, it seems to be fully supported, which is great!